# Integrated Rest API to wso2 API manager

Tags: api, rest, wso2, api-manager, wso2-esb

I want to connect my Secure rest API to the wso2 API manager. how I can header the Authorization key to the wso2 API manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable endpoint security to pass Authentication data to your secured backend. It supports Basic Auth, OAuth, and Digest Auth. Please refer to [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/design-api/endpoints/endpoint-security/oauth-2.0/).